# Create $n$ subset of $S$ so that union of any $k$ of them is equal to $S$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a set `S`, how to create `n` subset S<sub>1</sub>, ... S<sub>n</sub> of `S`, so that union of any `k` of them is equal to `S` but no `k-1` unions equals to `S`.

Example:

```
S = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
n = 5
k = 3
S1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
S2 = {0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8}
S3 = {0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9}
S4 = {1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9}
S5 = {2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}

|S|=10
1<=n<=9
1<=k<=n
```

I have observed that, every element in `S` is repeated `n-k+1` times. But stuck there.
Any useful thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Suppose $S$ has $1$ element, $k = 2$, and $n = 4$. It certainly appears to me that there's no solution. Since you cannot solve the problem in general, I think perhaps you're missing an assumption about the size of $S$, the value of $n$, and the value of $k$. Did you perhaps fail to transcribe some important element of the problem?

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks for your feedback! Please note that I have edited question.